# Freelance Gig Offering

Tags: discussion

Is it OK to share freelance opportunities on this site?  I'm a freelancer myself, and from time to time have need for specific skill sets for my clients.

Comment: Nope.  Voting to close this.

Answer (score 8):

**NO**. We do not allow advertising in the form of quesions on this site. However, Stack Overflow (the new name for the company who owns the SE Network of Sites) does allow advertising in the form of banner ads, or job ads on their Careers site. Please see [this link](http://stackexchange.com/mediakit) for more information.

Comment: This isn't an advertisement; I am not a headhunter. I'm the Beta test manager and we have a need to get some GUI stuff done before we can put the product in front of some new users. A specific skill set is all I need, for a short period of time, payment by grant award.@codenoire

Comment: @ContractMom Same issue. We do not allow these types of solicitations on the network.